# Submitting an array using form_tag with dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to submit an array of emails via a form_tag in Rails 4.

new.html.erb:

```
...
<%= render partial: 'add_user' %>
<%= render partial: 'new_ride_form' %>
...
```

_add_user.html.erb:

```
...
            <input type='text' id='add_passenger_textfield'/>
            <button type='button' id='add_passenger_button'>Add</button>
...
```

_new_ride_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag("/rides", method: "post", id: 'create_ride_submission_form') do %>
<div class="row" id="first_passenger">
...
</div>

<div class="row">
    <button id= 'create_ride_button'>Create Ride</button>
</div>

<% end %>
```

rides.js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_passenger_button', 
        function() {
          var v = $('#add_passenger_textfield').val();
          if(v.length > 0) {
            $('#first_passenger').after( 
              $('<div class="row"/>').append(
                $('<div>').append(
                  $('<input name="emails[]" type="text" value=' + v + ' disabled/>'))
                ));
          }
        }).on('click', '#create_ride_button', function() {
                ...
              $('#create_ride_submission_form').submit();
            }
        });
```

I want to get `params[:emails]` visible to the controller.

Before, when I just statically included something like

```
<text_field_tag 'emails[]'>
```

it seemed to work fine, but now the POST doesn't even send a field called "emails" anymore. Is this because I'm not using a form helper for the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled form elements are not getting send to the server. Your input element in the javascript part is disabled and unless you're enabling it somewhere else it won't reach your controller ever.

Comment: Wow, as usual the mistake is very stupid :) I changed it from 'disabled' to 'readonly' and it works now! Thanks!